# Enable custom JDBC Driver to work with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a custom JDBC driver. The driver is working correctly when instantiated and used directly, or when retrieved via `DriverManager.getConnection`.

At the moment I'm trying to allow my JDBC driver to work in Oracle SQL Developer, since it supports 3rd party JDBC drivers. What isn't clear to me is what additional methods or properties I need to implement in order for SQL Developer to recognize my driver.

I've followed the fairly simple online instructions to add my library to SQL Developer as a 3rd party JDBC driver, but after restarting my driver does not appear when trying to add a new connection.

**Update**
Added `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file with my JDBC driver listed.

Already have static self registration:

```
static {
    try {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new CustomDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your custom driver declare itself in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` in its Jar?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I did not have it declared in the services file.  I added it, and I verified in the jar that META-INF is in the root of the jar and the file is in the correct location (per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) but SQL Developer still does not show any indication of seeing my driver.  The only indication that it even touched the jar is that if SQL Developer is open there is a file lock on my jar and I have to close the app before updating it with a new try.

Comment: And your driver has a static initializer to register itself?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I had that one already, I put the exact code as an update to my question.

Comment: Ok, I would expect that to be sufficient, but I am assuming that SQL Developer uses the normal JDBC mechanisms, and I don't know if that is actually the case.

Comment: According to Jeff Smith, the 3rd party JDBC support can only used for migration: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/

Comment: @UlfJaehrig: I read the article; and that all sounds perfectly fine to me. I'll be happy with read-only support.  I downloaded the Teradata JDBC driver and loaded it into SQL Developer and it loaded immediately; now I have a new tab for establishing connections with Teradata.  I looked through the decompiled code a bit but nothing jumps out at me, except that I have no idea where all the fields showing up in the GUI are being defined in code...

Comment: Maybe @thatjeffsmith can help you. As the product manager of SQL Developer he might have a better insight what's needed from a JDBC driver to be loadable.